Add vertical scroll bar to combobox Windows form Visual Studio Graphical Editor
So i am using the windows form graphical editor in Visual Studio 2022 using the .net framework. I have a list of data that i have put into the Items property for a ComboBox. I would like to have a limited number of items displayed and then be able to scroll through all the items using a vertical scroll bar. I have set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList and set MaxDropDownItems to 8 but it just displays all the items in one long list without a scroll bar. Any help would be appreciated.

So i found a solution. In MyForm_Load i put the following line of code.
this->comboboxCharacters->DropDownHeight = this->comboboxCharacters->ItemHeight * 8;

this shows only 8 elements at a time and has a scroll bar.
